# Object variables in C++ hold values, not object references

Tags: c++, object, reference

At: http://www.horstmann.com/ccj2/ccjapp3.html, under **A3.4. Objects**, mentioned the following:

> In C++, object variables hold values, not object references

Can you clarify this point? And, is it only the `pointer` in C++ that holds object references?

Can we say here that the `object reference` is the `object address`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you clarify this point?

It's best to understand by comparison with e.g. Java or C#:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass; // creates an instance.
MyClass b = a; // we still have one instance of MyClass in memory
```

In contrast in C++:

```
MyClass a; // a *is* an instance of MyClass.
MyClass b = a; // we make a copy of a, now there are *two* instances of MyClass.
```

> And, is it only the pointer in C++ that holds object references?

No, references too.

> Can we say here that the object reference is the object address?

No, if you mean a `A&` reference, then it's an implementation detail. Also you may implement objects with reference semantics that work like in C#. `xml_node` in pugixml library is an example:

```
xml_node root = ...;
xml_node root2 = root; // doesn't copy the document
// root2 refers to the same object as root.
```

Answer (score 5):

C++ supports the concepts of value/pointer/reference. A value is like a Java `int` if you pass it to a function which modifies the argument, the original value is unchanged, this is known as value semantics.

In Java most objects have reference semantics, which means that a variable doesn't store an object, it stores a reference to an object so that if the object is modified via one reference all other references see the changes. This is also supported in C++ with references and pointers. Pointers are the memory address of the object and references behave in a semantically similar way (and are usually implemented with pointers behind the scenes). It's not correct to say that a reference is the object's address, an object's address would be a pointer to the object.

For more details see [Reference and value semantics](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/value-vs-ref-semantics.html).

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little too much detail, but, to be precise, a pointer is an object variable that stores the address of another object and has an entity of itself: you can request the address of a pointer, you can modify a pointer...

References (C++ sense, not Java) are not object variables (in the current standard, I believe there is some rewording going into c++0x around this), but rather *aliases* to objects. There are a few technical details around this, like for example the fact that you can create arrays of objects, but you cannot create arrays of references (references not being objects).

Now, if you are coming from a Java background, what you really need to remember is that (while not exactly the same) Java variables and C++ pointers are similar things: they hold the key to access an object somewhere, but the concept of C++ reference is not available in Java. This is the reason that you cannot implement a `swap` operation in Java, except for some specific types:

```
template <typename T>
void swap( T & lhs, T & rhs )
{
   T tmp = lhs;
   lhs = rhs;
   rhs = tmp;
}
int main() {
   int a = 1, b = 5; 
   swap( a, b );      // a == 5, b == 1 after this call in this context
}
```

If you keep that in mind and you understand that in Java references are passed by value (a copy of the reference is passed to the function) then you have taken a good step into understanding C++ function call semantics.

Answer (score 1):

An object reference is an permanant, fixed, and implicit address of an object. Whereas a pointer is a mutable, explicit address variable. In other words, a refernce uses an object's address to access the object, but 1) it does not make that address available to the programmer, and 2) a reference is permanantly bound to a particular object. A pointer can point to any object of a particular type, or no object at all. Initialization is not mandatory. Furthermore, since a pointer is a variable, it can be reassigned at will.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in C++ pointers hold object references,there´s the & operator that do a implit reference too.
Java and c++ have different behaviors.
IN java:

```
myobject a;
a = new myobject();
```

In C++:

```
myobject a;
```

or
     myobject *a;
     a = new myobject();

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the default is to pass and store objects by value.  So if you have

```
class A {
    int x[5000];
}
```

This creates a type that stores 5000 ints.  If you then have a class that uses A like so:

```
class B {
    A content;
};
```

then every B has an array of 5000 ints in it.  This contrasts with a language like Java, where content would be something like a pointer to A.

In C++ you have the option to make content a pointer to A:

```
class C {
    A* content;
};
```

or a reference to A

```
class D {
    A& content;
};
```

but you must do so explicitly.  Also, references in C++ can't be null, so if there is a possibility that the value of content is undefined, you must use a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are three different kinds of variables in C++. Values, references and pointers. What the first one, value, means is that if you define

```
int a;
```

or

```
SomeOtherType a;
```

and it means that you create a new object of that type and memory gets reserved to store it. And then you can for example copy its contents to another variable by writing

```
another_variable = a;
```

If you use pointers instead, like this:

```
SomeType *a = &some_existing_variable;
```

then if you say "b = a;" where a and b are both pointers, you don't copy any data but you just change to which object those pointers point to. References work much in the same way. The most important differences between pointers and references are that a reference can't be NULL, you must initialize a reference, you can't change the value of a reference and that the syntax to use with them is different.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most visual ways to interpret the difference between object variables and pointer variables has do with the location where the memory is allocated: object variables refer to stack objects, while pointers (and references) may refer (usually) to heap objects. Both are constructed differently, have different life spans, and each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Check out the "Stack and Heap" section of my article: 
http://akos.ma/188y